# Does ServletContext get updated during the request

Tags: java, servlets

Does ServletContext get updated during the request. for example I have this code:

```
public void action(@Context ServletContext context) {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  Object object = context.getAttribute("data");
}
```

will object point to the data stored in the attribute when the function `action` got called, or the the data stored 5 seconds later, when `getAttribute` is called?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html):

> [...] There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. [...]

So the servlet context is some kind of a global variable. Other parts of the web application can modify it concurrently.